How do I make the content behind the modal functional?
I want to implement a bottom sheet button but I want the content behind it to be able to be manipulated without the bottom sheet closing.
I'm trying to use IonModal but it doesn't allow me to.
I also tried using react-spring-bottom but it gave me implementation problems with ionic. Any alternatives?


I created a reusable solution using React Spring for smooth animations which you can find below:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring';

const PersistentBottomSheet = ({ children, minHeight = 100, maxHeight = 400 }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  
  const springProps = useSpring({
    height: isExpanded ? maxHeight : minHeight,
    config: {
      tension: 300,
      friction: 30
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-50">
      <animated.div 
        style={springProps}
        className="bg-white rounded-t-xl shadow-lg w-full overflow-hidden"
      >
        {/* Handle bar for dragging */}
        <div 
          className="w-full py-4 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
        >
          <div className="w-12 h-1 bg-gray-300 rounded-full mx-auto" />
        </div>
        
        {/* Content area */}
        <div className="px-4 overflow-y-auto">
          {children}
        </div>
      </animated.div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Example usage
const ExampleApp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen bg-gray-100">
      {/* Your main content here */}
      <div className="p-4">
        <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Main Content</h1>
        <p>This content remains interactive when the bottom sheet is open</p>
      </div>
      
      <PersistentBottomSheet>
        <div className="space-y-4">
          <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold">Bottom Sheet Content</h2>
          <p>This is the content of your bottom sheet.</p>
          <button className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
            Action Button
          </button>
        </div>
      </PersistentBottomSheet>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExampleApp;

To use this component:
Install React Spring if you haven't already:
npm install @react-spring/web

Copy the component code and use it in your application
You can customize the styling using Tailwind classes or your preferred styling solution
Hope this helps

Bro thanks you very much, you are like god to me, Literaly solved my problem in five minutes. I love you

Glad I could be of help. You're welcome! :-)
